# Assign an array subscript to another array

Tags: arrays, vba

How can assign the fourth subscript of `arr1(ind1,ind2,ind3,ind4)` which `ind1=x`, `ind2=y`, `ind3=z`; to `arr2()`?

```
Sub ArrAsignment()
   Dim arr1(10, 5, 7, 13) As String
   Dim arr2(13) As String

   ' codes to assign values to arr1...

   arr2 = arr1(2,2 ,2 , )

End Sub
```

Comment: You want the 4th element of arr2 to be an array of 14 elements? I think you'd have to loop with a 4d array.

Comment: You declared arr1() As String and then filled it with values. Would you like to use one of the fourth 14 elements array one? If yes, you need to define which of them. If you need the fourth arr1() element, this one being an array, you cannot do that because you declared arr2() As String and a type mismatch error will occur, I think. In such a case, it would be good to declare it As Variant. What would you like to do, in fact?

Comment: @FaneDuru, I want fourth subscript elements of `arr1` wich specified ***first***, ***second*** and ***third*** subscripts, as you guess in ("If you need the fourth arr1() element"), assign to `arr2` which is an array. I want assign this array to `arr2`. `arr1` and `arr2` are string declared.

Comment: @SJR, You right. I think about most quick and better programming this in VBA.

Comment: You can use this code: `arr2(0) = Array(arr1(0, 0, 0, 0), arr1(0, 0, 0, 1), arr1(0, 0, 0, 2))`, but it will work only if you would declare arr2 As Variant: `Dim arr2(13) As Variant`. Of course, if I correctly understood what you need...

Comment: @FaneDuru, Is there a better programmatically approach in VB, for cases the arr1 subscripts may dynamically change with `Redim Preserve` ?

Comment: Is there a built-in command in VB for assign `arr1(2,2,2, 0 to 13 )` to `arr2`, without loop?

Comment: Yes, you can dinamically use 'Redim Preserve', but only for the last column. There is not such a built command, but there can be some workarounds using Index. I will try something  when I will be at home, if somebody else will not find a solution...

Comment: You can slice a 2D array but am not aware of a method for 4D. But looping through arrays is quick so what's the problem?

Comment: The best solution for this, with best performance high programming value.